# Scala Function founds Unit while i return boolean

Tags: scala, list

Im getting error in if(Liste.length>1), i want to make a function to return true if list is ordered low to high. Having some problems with Boolean returning.

```
object Soru5 extends App {
  //A function returns true if list is ordered low to high
  def kucukten_buyuge_siralimi(Liste:List[Int]):Boolean=
  {
      var i=0
      var ListeIslem=Liste
      if(Liste.length==0) false
      if(Liste.length==1) true
      if(Liste.length>1) //***********ERROR************ found->Unit,Boolean required
      {
        while(i<Liste.length-1)
        {
          var onceki=ListeIslem.head //onceki is first element of list
          var sonraki=(ListeIslem.tail).head //sonraki is second element of list
          if(onceki>sonraki)
            {
              return false
            }
          else
            {
              ListeIslem=ListeIslem.tail
              i=i+1
            }
        }
        return true
      }

  }
  val listem=List(3,2,1)
  println(kucukten_buyuge_siralimi(listem))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because there's no `else` between `if`s, they are separate. You effectively have

   ```
   if (Liste.length==0) false else ();
   if (Liste.length==1) true else ();
   if (Liste.length>1) ... else ();
   ```

   `else ()` is what the compiler inserts for every `if` without `else`.
2. The compiler has no idea that `Liste.length` will be the same each time or that it will never be negative. It would be better to write

   ```
   Liste.length match {
     case 0 => false
     case 1 => true
     case n => ...
   ```

   You can use `n` in the last branch instead of calculating length yet again.

This can be improved further, of course, but I think it's out of scope for this answer.

Comment: I also didn't mention that mathematically speaking an empty list is normally considered to be ordered.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of a method is the value of the last expression evaluated inside the method body. In your case, the last expression inside the method body is:

```
if(Liste.length>1) {
  // …
}
```

So … what is the value of this expression if the length is less than 2? *There is no value!* Actually, in Scala, there is (almost) *always* a value, so the value of this is `()` which is of type `Unit` and denotes the absence of a value.

In other words, if the length is less than 2, your method will return `()` of type `Unit`, but it promises to return something of type `Boolean`. You need to add an `else` clause to your `if` expression that also returns a `Boolean`.

This is the immediate cause of the error.

Note that there are also some other problems with your code besides that. For example, those two lines don't actually do anything:

```
if(Liste.length==0) false
if(Liste.length==1) true
```

They simply evaluate to a value, but you don't actually do anything with that value, you don't store it in a variable, you don't return it, you don't pass it as an argument … it just vanishes.

Note also that your code violates the Community Coding Style.

And last but not least, your code just doesn't read like Scala. It reads more like a mix of Fortran and Basic. Scala style would be more like this:

```
def isMonotonicallyIncreasing(l: List[Int]) =
  if (l.size < 2) true else l.sliding(2).forall { case (a :: b :: Nil) ⇒ a <= b }
```

i.e. a list is monotonically increasing if for all subsequent pairs of elements, the left element is not greater than the right element.